# Automatically accept photo taken from camera to help blind users

Tags: android, flutter

I am building a visual helper application with Flutter and I am using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package to pick an image from camera.

Since my application must be used by blind users, I would like to know how to automatically accept a picture taken with the camera. Blind users can shoot a photo at whatever they have in front by tapping the lower volume button, but then the check must be tapped, so I would like to know if there is some way to automatically tap the check button shown below and accept the image in the application. Even using other libraries is fine for me if they allow for this.

[image]

Comment: There are hundreds, if not thousands, of camera apps. Not all have to have that button in that spot that does this specific action. How do plan on testing and supporting all of the different camera apps?

Comment: @CommonsWare not sure I got ur point, this is a screen created by the image_picker plugin, I am justing searching for another plugin that does not have this confirm button, do you have one to suggest?

Comment: You can implement a Flutter version of the image selector by yourself, add semanticsLabel for blind people, it provides semantics